# универсальный xpath для сайта

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

есть на сайте бинанса ордера в разделе покупки/продажи, и там есть лимиты. минимум и максимум

необходимо парсить минимум и максимум у 10 ордеров (всего их на странцие)

xpath минимума 1-го ордера - `/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/main/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]`

xpath минимума 2-го ордера - `/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/main/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]`

какой xpath написать в методе selenium find_elements(By.XPATH), чтобы он получил все 10 минимумов ордеров?

Comment: `/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/main/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]`
убрал тот спецификатор порядкового номера, в котором эти пути отличаются.

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Они одинаковые.
Вы можете использовать не full XPath, а просто XPath.
В любом случае find_elementS выведет список найденных объектов.

Answer (score 1):

Метод `find_elements` возвращает массив, который содержит все элементы, удовлетворяющие условию поиска.

Однако, приведенные в вопросе xpath - плохая практика, они содержат явный путь через весь DOM, что:

1. Плохо читаемо
2. При любых изменениях в DOM веб-сайта придется обновлять xpath

Лучше использовать что-то наподобие:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'navbar')]"))
```

P.S. Если нужна помощь в написании xpath для вашего конкретного случая, прикрепите полный DOM